# How to match repetition of a word in regular expression of perl

Tags: regex, perl

The situation is very simple. The word "gat" may appear 0 or 1 time in a string. How can I write regex to match it?

Right now I can only use the following to do what I want. It works in my situation, though it would also match "ga", "at" etc.

```
$str =~ m/(g?a?t?)/
```

I guess there is a much easier expression to use "?" on the word "gat", but I tried "{}" and it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [Non-capturing Group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Non-capturing-groupings) and the [`?` quantifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions)

```
$str =~ m/...(?:gat)?.../
```

Can also be written as:

```
$str =~ m/...(?:gat){0,1}.../
```

Comment: Thanks @Miller and @M42! Non-capturing group is exactly what I want, but what do the three dots mean? I tried and I think it works without three dots

Comment: @Michael Yeah, the three dots are a mystery...  ;)

Comment: @Michael The three dots are placeholders assuming this is part of a bigger regular expression.  Because if it isn't then the regex would match literally any string.

Comment: A dot isn't exactly a great placeholder in a regular expression. :) But then, what's a better placeholder?

Answer (score 1):

```
.*?(\b(?:gat)\b)?
```

Try this.This will give all gat.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/33

Comment: Thanks vks for the answer and the very nice online tool there! I think your solution doesn't match the case when "gat" doesn't appear in the string.

Comment: Yes, non-capturing group. I tried to understand the word boundary. Does it mean what's between the pair of "\b" must be a word?

Comment: @Michael yes \b asserts position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W).It can be one of these four.